# How do I replace matching columns to row values with a value

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
> head(mt)
      FID  IID   PLATE 0VXC556 1CNF297 1CWO500 1DXJ626 1LTX827 1SHK635 1TNP840
1 fam0110 G110 4RWG569      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2 fam0113 G113  cherry      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3 fam0114 G114  cherry      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
4 fam0117 G117 4RWG569      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
5 fam0118 G118 5XAV049      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
6 fam0119 G119  cherry      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
 1URP242 2BKX529 2PAG415 3DEF425 3ECO791 3FQM386 3KYJ479 3XHK903 4RWG569
1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
4      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
5      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
6      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
  5AMJ101 5AVC089 5GBM583 5XAV049 5ZCV995 6KAE204 6PKP514 6WZD253 7FDZ321
1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
4      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
5      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
6      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
  7MFL836 7PNN733 7RUZ165 8WWR250 9GXO476 9QYW461 9RHL593 9TKZ501 cherry
1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
2      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
3      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
4      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
5      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
6      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
...
```

how do I replace every NA i every column with 2 if the column name matches row value in mt$PLATE and with 1 if that is not true?

for example the first row of mt would only have mt$`4RWG569`==2 and every other column would be equal 1 in that row.

I tried doing this:

```
idxs <- t(mapply(cbind, match(colnames(mt), mt$PLATE)))
```

but then when I tried to this:

```
> mt[idxs] <- "2"
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, idxs, value = "2") : 
  unsupported matrix index in replacement
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this line solves it:

```
for(i in 4:ncol(mt)) mt[,i] <- 1 + (names(mt)[i]== mt$PLATE)
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27275592).